# Stupid Simple Syntax Error

Tags: jquery

Trying to make a textarea expand on focus, and contract back to original size on focus. I keep getting syntax errors. I know this is a basic jQuery structure, but I can't get the part right where focus is removed.

```
$("textarea").focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({"height": "250px"});
}, function() {
   $(this).animate({"height": "50px"});
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second `});` line.

This code can be rewritten to be slightly easier to understand.

```
var on = function() {
    $(this).animate({"height": "250px"});
};
var off = function() {
   $(this).animate({"height": "50px"});
};
$("textarea").focus(on, off);
```

If you remove unnecessary local variables `on` and `off`, you'll get the code you had (except the wrong part).

**edit**
Also, [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus) method takes only one handler (unlike `hover`). If you want to execute code when element looses focus, use [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Comment: @Dirty - @Nikita's edit is the important part: the ".focus()" API only takes one function, not two like ".hover()".

Comment: @Nikiita - awesome, I just had to add $(textarea).blur(off); after $("textarea").focus(on); to get it to work just right. I have 2 questions though, it didn't seem to work with $(textarea).focus(on, off); is that due to the edit you had? and this is stupid but why did you only use a "};" after the function () { calls? dont they have to end with )};?

Comment: @Dirty 1) It's due to the fact that `focus` method takes only one handler. Do read the documentation I linked :)  2) `)` in `});` closes `focus(`, not function declaration. So, method is called like `focus(param1, param2)`. And function is declared like `function(param1, param2) { // code here }`.

Comment: @Nikkita - thanks a lot, I really appreciate it and learned something from you here.